# WCF netNamedPipeBinding Error?

Tags: c#, wcf

My **Self-hosted** WCF service hang randomly.By looking with **Microsoft Service Trace Viewer** I conclude that my net named piped service (local socket) timeout by following the log.

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131075</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-03T11:23:05.0676326Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{4f3405dc-fda1-42a1-b825-64b85cb07b6b}" /><Execution ProcessName="MyServiceHosting" ProcessID="2708" ThreadID="52" /><Channel /><Computer>SERVER</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Error"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Throwing an exception.</Description><AppDomain>KaraokeServiceHosting.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException, System.ServiceModel, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '10675199.02:48:05.4775807'. ---&amp;gt; System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.DelegatingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.TracingConnection.EndRead()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SessionConnectionReader.OnAsyncReadComplete(Object state)</ExceptionString><InnerException><ExceptionType>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException, System, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.Net.Sockets.SocketException (0x80004005): An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.HandleReceiveAsyncCompleted()
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.OnReceiveAsync(Object sender, SocketAsyncEventArgs eventArgs)</ExceptionString><NativeErrorCode>2746</NativeErrorCode></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

After the above log , I found out that an exception about **"result argument must be of type Message"**

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131076</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Error">0</SubType><Level>2</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-03T11:25:25.3043639Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{99bbd683-75e0-48ee-b405-16d3ab9c06a6}" /><Execution ProcessName="MyServiceHosting" ProcessID="1376" ThreadID="6" /><Channel /><Computer>SERVER</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord Severity="Error" Channel="Operational" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.TraceHandledException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Handling an exception. Exception details: System.ArgumentException: The 'result' argument must be of type Message.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageOperationFormatter.SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.SerializeOutputs(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</Description><AppDomain>KaraokeServiceHosting.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.ArgumentException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The 'result' argument must be of type Message.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageOperationFormatter.SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.SerializeOutputs(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ArgumentException: The 'result' argument must be of type Message.
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageOperationFormatter.SerializeReply(MessageVersion messageVersion, Object[] parameters, Object result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.SerializeOutputs(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DispatchOperationRuntime.InvokeBegin(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage5(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage41(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage4(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage31(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage3(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage2(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage11(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage1(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

and **"destination is unknown"** exception

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>131075</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Warning">0</SubType><Level>4</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-03T11:25:25.3199765Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{99bbd683-75e0-48ee-b405-16d3ab9c06a6}" /><Execution ProcessName="MyServiceHosting" ProcessID="1376" ThreadID="4" /><Channel /><Computer>SERVER</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord Severity="Warning" Channel="Analytic" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Diagnostics.ThrowingException.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>Throwing an exception. Source: System.ServiceModel 4.0.0.0. Exception details: System.InvalidOperationException: The supplied message cannot be sent because the destination is unknown.  This transport requires that either Message.Headers.To or Message.Properties.Via be set to a valid value on the outgoing message.</Description><AppDomain>KaraokeServiceHosting.exe</AppDomain><Exception><ExceptionType>System.InvalidOperationException, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089</ExceptionType><Message>The supplied message cannot be sent because the destination is unknown.  This transport requires that either Message.Headers.To or Message.Properties.Via be set to a valid value on the outgoing message.</Message><StackTrace>   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.WriteExceptionToTraceString(XmlTextWriter xml, Exception exception, Int32 remainingLength, Int32 remainingAllowedRecursionDepth)
   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.ExceptionToTraceString(Exception exception, Int32 maxTraceStringLength)
   at System.Runtime.Diagnostics.EtwDiagnosticTrace.GetSerializedPayload(Object source, TraceRecord traceRecord, Exception exception, Boolean getServiceReference)
   at System.Runtime.TraceCore.ThrowingException(EtwDiagnosticTrace trace, String param0, String param1, Exception exception)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionTrace.TraceException[TException](TException exception, String eventSource)
   at System.Runtime.ExceptionTrace.AsError(Exception exception)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.ServerUdpOutputChannel.GetSendSockets(Message message, IPEndPoint&amp;amp; remoteEndPoint, Exception&amp;amp; exceptionToBeThrown)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpOutputChannel.SendAsyncResult.Initialize(Message message)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpOutputChannel.SendAsyncResult..ctor(UdpOutputChannel channel, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpOutputChannel.OnBeginSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.OutputChannel.BeginSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.UdpDuplexChannel.BeginSend(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.DuplexRequestContext.ReplyAsyncResult..ctor(DuplexRequestContext context, Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder.DuplexRequestContext.OnBeginReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextBase.BeginReply(Message message, TimeSpan timeout, AsyncCallback callback, Object state)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.BeginReply(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage9(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ImmutableDispatchRuntime.ProcessMessage8(MessageRpc&amp;amp; rpc)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.ProcessError(Exception e)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.MessageRpc.Process(Boolean isOperationContextSet)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.DispatchAndReleasePump(RequestContext request, Boolean cleanThread, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.HandleRequest(RequestContext request, OperationContext currentOperationContext)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.AsyncMessagePump(IAsyncResult result)
   at System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.ChannelHandler.OnContinueAsyncReceive(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.ActionItem.DefaultActionItem.TraceAndInvoke()
   at System.Runtime.ActionItem.DefaultActionItem.Invoke()
   at System.Runtime.ActionItem.CallbackHelper.InvokeWithoutContext(Object state)
   at System.Runtime.IOThreadScheduler.ScheduledOverlapped.IOCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Runtime.Fx.IOCompletionThunk.UnhandledExceptionFrame(UInt32 error, UInt32 bytesRead, NativeOverlapped* nativeOverlapped)
   at System.Threading._IOCompletionCallback.PerformIOCompletionCallback(UInt32 errorCode, UInt32 numBytes, NativeOverlapped* pOVERLAP)
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.InvalidOperationException: The supplied message cannot be sent because the destination is unknown.  This transport requires that either Message.Headers.To or Message.Properties.Via be set to a valid value on the outgoing message.</ExceptionString></Exception></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

follow by **"RequestContext aborted"** warning

```
<E2ETraceEvent xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/E2ETraceEvent"><System xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/06/windows/eventlog/system"><EventID>262174</EventID><Type>3</Type><SubType Name="Warning">0</SubType><Level>4</Level><TimeCreated SystemTime="2015-04-03T11:25:25.3199765Z" /><Source Name="System.ServiceModel" /><Correlation ActivityID="{99bbd683-75e0-48ee-b405-16d3ab9c06a6}" /><Execution ProcessName="MyServiceHosting" ProcessID="1376" ThreadID="4" /><Channel /><Computer>SERVER</Computer></System><ApplicationData><TraceData><DataItem><TraceRecord xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2004/10/E2ETraceEvent/TraceRecord" Severity="Warning"><TraceIdentifier>http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/System.ServiceModel.Channels.RequestContextAbort.aspx</TraceIdentifier><Description>RequestContext aborted</Description><AppDomain>KaraokeServiceHosting.exe</AppDomain><Source>System.ServiceModel.Dispatcher.DuplexChannelBinder+DuplexRequestContext/59817589</Source></TraceRecord></DataItem></TraceData></ApplicationData></E2ETraceEvent>
```

By changing the named piped timeout duration can I solve the problem? Or is there any odifferent problem? Since I am beginner at reading trace log, I may read what the trace log is showing incorrectly.

Comment: The above errors are from your client application, correct? If so, is the server application up and running? Is your service hosted in IIS or is it a console application? Is the service app running?

Comment: Also, is the Net.Pipe Listener Adapter windows service running?

Comment: @ajawad987 I am thinking it was from WCF service and not from wcf client because you can see **Local socket timeout** , in the first log. My WCF service is hosted on a Window Form and neither on IIS or console application? You can say the service app (Window Form which was hosted on) hang.

Comment: @ajawad987 Although I don't understand what you mean by Net.Pipe Listener Adapter , I am getting the above log by adding 
`<listeners>
          <add name="sdt" type="System.Diagnostics.XmlWriterTraceListener" initializeData="C:\WCFLog\logclient.svclog" />
        </listeners>` in "App.config" file

Comment: Since your using the Net Pipe binding type, you'll need to ensure that the underlying Net.Pipe Listener Adapter Windows Service for it is also running. You can check in the Control Panel | Administrative Tools | Services utility. This service is needed by WCF to use the pipe communication method between your applications.

Comment: @ajawad987 Thank for replying. I think I don't make my question clear. I can run the WCF service correctly but after a certain period (random, 5 hour,6 hour,---etc) my Window Form which hosted the service hang. I don't mean that my WCF service does not run correctly , what I mean is that it hang after a certain period of time which I suspect is because the time out duration of net pipe.